# How to and how much to clean the HEPA filter?

Tags: cleaning, filter

I'm trying to clean this HEPA filter from my vacuum cleaner by washing* it and even though I've managed to get most of the dirtiness out, there's still some left sticking to the corners between each layer.

[image]

I can't reach there without a pointy object and I'm afraid of puncturing the sheet.

1. Do I need to clean that much? (how much suction do I lose if I don't)
2. What's a safe way to do so?

*I'm reading in some places that I shouldn't *wash* it, but the manual that came with my cleaner specifically told me to wash it. (and then dry)

Answer (score 1):

There are washable filters and one that can not be washed, trust the manual about that.

Don't worry over or fight the small spaces that did not get clean. You will annoy yourself, and be limited in how much you can clean them if you try.

View them as a very small reduction in the filter area, be proud that you are one of the few taking proper care of your filter, and enjoy your clean air.